# What are the ranges of the four $q$ parameters in the magic simplex of Bell states formula?

Tags: entanglement, density-matrix, bell-basis, photonics, ppt-criterion

Equation (7) in the 2012 paper, ["Complementarity Reveals Bound Entanglement of Two Twisted Photons" of B. C. Hiesmayr and W. Löffler](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5046) for a state $\rho_d$ in the "magic simplex" of Bell states
\begin{equation}
\rho_d= \frac{q_4 (1-\delta (d-3)) \sum _{z=2}^{d-2} \left(\sum _{i=0}^{d-1}
   P_{i,z}\right)}{d}+\frac{q_2 \sum _{i=1}^{d-1} P_{i,0}}{(d-1) (d+1)}+\frac{q_3 \sum
   _{i=0}^{d-1} P_{i,1}}{d}+\frac{\left(-\frac{q_1}{d^2-d-1}-\frac{q_2}{d+1}-(d-3)
   q_4-q_3+1\right) \text{IdentityMatrix}\left[d^2\right]}{d^2}+\frac{q_1
   P_{0,0}}{d^2-d-1}
\end{equation}
yields "for $d=3$ the one-parameter Horodecki-state, the first found bound entangled state".

No explicit ranges — in which I am interested — for the four $q$ parameters are given, though. Any thoughts/insights?

Comment: The d=4 question is the subject of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195707/solve-a-constrained-four-dimensional-integration-problem-for-a-magic-simplex-p

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the only relation they say is $\text{IdentityMatrix}[3^2]=\sum P_{k,l}$.

You get a linear combination of $P_{k,l}$. Those are vertices of a $d^2-1$ simplex so the coefficents $c_{k,l}$ are baryocentric coordinates.

You can then match with the previous more general definition of $\rho_d$ term by term on each of the $c_{k,l}$.

The inequalities $0 \leq c_{k,l} \leq 1$ turn into $2d^2$ inequalities on the $q_i$.

It looks like that how the $q_i$ were constructed in the first place.

Comment: For the $d=3$ case, the desired range conditions appear to be $0<q_1<5, 0<q_2<8, 0<q_3<3, q_1/5+q_2/8+q_3/3<1$. Utilizing this information, I have obtained for the Hilbert-Schmidt PPT-probability of the states $\rho_d$, as given in the formulation of the question, the result $-\frac{11}{35}+\frac{3 \pi }{8}-\frac{129 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{5
   \sqrt{7}}{16}\right)}{49 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{8 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{8
   \sqrt{2}}\right)}{7 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}(7)+\frac{157 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{5 \sqrt{7}}{9}\right)}{49 \sqrt{7}}  \approx 0.461554$. I will now try the $d=4$ case.

Comment: Second thoughts about the above formula.

Comment: Yes the formula does hold--using the range constraint $q_1>0, q_2>0, q_3>0, 0<1-q_1/5-q_2/4-q_3<1$.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater I've edited the formatting in your comments a bit.